# I keep getting these errors

Tags: c, operating-system

I keep getting the follow errors and I don't know what they really mean.
/tmp/ccIUS3m4.o: In function `main':
assign3_1.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to`pthread_create'
assign3_1.c:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/tmp/ccIUS3m4.o: In function`runner':
assign3_1.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Below is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_POINTS 1000000
#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 2

void *runner(void *param);
// circle size
int circle_count=0;

// generate a double precision random number
double random_double(){
        return random() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]){
        int points_per_thread = NUMBER_OF_POINTS/NUMBER_OF_THREADS;
        int i;
        double Pi;
        pthread_t workers[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

        //create random numbers
        srandom((unsigned)time(NULL));
        clock_t begin = clock();
        for (i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
                pthread_create(&workers[i], 0, runner, &points_per_thread);

        for(i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
                pthread_join(workers[i],NULL);


        //estimating Pi
        Pi = 4.0 * circle_count / NUMBER_OF_POINTS;
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("NUMBER OF POINTS = %d\n", NUMBER_OF_POINTS);
        printf("Pi = %f\n",Pi);
        printf("time = %f\n",time_spent);
        return 0;
        }

void *runner(void *param){
        int POINTS;
        POINTS = *((int *)param);
        int i;
        int hit_count = 0;
        double x, y;

        for(i=0; i < POINTS; i++){
                //generate numbers b/w -1.0 to +1.0
                //to obtain a random (x, y) coordinates
                x = random_double() * 2.0 - 1.0;
                y = random_double() * 2.0 - 1.0;

                //are the points within the circle?
                if (sqrt(x*x + y*y) < 1.0)
                        ++hit_count; //yes
        }

        circle_count += hit_count;

        pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419163/linking-pthread-library-issue  ...  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33396/gcc-cant-link-to-pthread

Comment: @yano I know it this error: /tmp/ccEFF0C6.o: In function `runner':
assign3_1.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: for `sqrt` you need to link in the math library: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332884/how-to-compile-a-c-program-that-uses-math-h

Comment: @yano I did as shown above in my code

Comment: including a header file (math.h in this case) is not the same thing as linking in a library. A header file consists of function declarations. The actual binary executable code is in the library.. in this case, the math library. You link in the math library by adding `-lm` to your build command just like the link says.

Comment: @yano that makes so much sense. Thank you

Comment: did you remember to add the library `pthread` when linking?  The error messages seem to indicate that library is not included